# Restarting a Kubernetes job if it is evicted but not if it fails?

Tags: kubernetes, batch-processing

I'm working with an autoscaling Kubernetes cluster. If a `Job`'s pod is running on an under-utilized node, the node will be destroyed and the job's pod will be evicted.

**I want the job's pod to start running on another node if it is evicted** because the node it was trying to run on was destroyed. But **I *don't* want the job to restart if the container exits with a nonzero exit code**, or exceeds its resource limits. (Usually in my environment a nonzero exit code or limit exhaustion means the job can't succeed, and I don't want my cluster to be scaled up larger than it needs to be for a long time to run all these restarts, wasting compute.)

Is this possible?

My reading of the docs is that there's one pool of pod recreations set by `backoffLimit`. It looks like, while you can set an `OnFailure` restart policy to rerun in place, without consuming these, if the code in the container fails, you can't prevent the job from being restarted up to `backoffLimit` times if it returns failure. It also looks like the pod won't be restarted after eviction if it has hit `backoffLimit`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with default kubernetes schduler. Do you think a [custom scheduler](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/k8s-custom-scheduler/) is a viable alternative in your case?

Comment: I am considering setting up Volcano as a custom scheduler, so if Volcano (or its Job CRD) can do this, that would be useful to know.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be possible in future version of K8 (beta as of 1.26). See sample below where it ignores failures due to few evictions i.e. disruption.

More on: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#pod-failure-policy

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job-pod-failure-policy-example
spec:
  completions: 12
  parallelism: 3
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: main
        image: docker.io/library/bash:5
        command: ["bash"]        # example command simulating a bug which triggers the FailJob action
        args:
        - -c
        - echo "Hello world!" && sleep 5 && exit 42
  backoffLimit: 6
  podFailurePolicy:
    rules:
    - action: FailJob
      onExitCodes:
        containerName: main      # optional
        operator: In             # one of: In, NotIn
        values: [42]
    - action: Ignore             # one of: Ignore, FailJob, Count
      onPodConditions:
      - type: DisruptionTarget   # indicates Pod disruption
```